# On starting feature engineering

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I would like to start my feature engineering process by first selecting a subset of features that are highly correlated with the target feature.

However, if I do select let’s say the top k in terms of correlation, won’t I be implicitly selecting k features that are also highly correlated among one another?

If yes, isn’t this kind of a bad thing because in a way I am just picking the same vectors in space? Wouldn’t it be a good idea to also make sure that among these k features I am picking the ones that are less correlated with one another ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlation between x and y and z and y does not imply correlation between x and z.  For example if x and z are iid uniform (0,1) random variables and y = x + z you will find that x and z have correlation 0 but the correlation between y and x (and similarly y and z) will be about 0.7.